# How to update component that is being rendered on route of 'react-router-dom'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When my App runs componentDidMount() I fetch the data

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    let players = await playersDAO.read();
    this.setState({ players: players });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Then show it on a component that is being rendered by Route from react-router-dom

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      key="players"
      path="/players"
      render={() => <Players rows={this.state.players} />}
    />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I don't know why, but when the data is fetched the component do not update. Maybe(there's a large chance) I'm doing something wrong, but can anyone help me with it?

Off-topic: I use the render propriety of Route, because i need to pass props for my component, anyone knows a better way of doing so?

Comment: I think you are misusing the `Router`. If you need it to update it means for me that it shouldn't be a `Route` but a component tree rendering instead. Routes are like html `a` tags.

Comment: `Routes are like html a tags` you seem to be thinking of `<Link>`s, @RafaelMora

Comment: @NicholasTower no I am not. I'm just trying to explain to @CarlosJunior what is like to use the `Routes`.

Comment: @CarlosJunior: Using a Route with path="/players" means that the Players component will only render if the url ends in "/players", as in `http://localhost:3000/players`. Is that what you want? If so, did you set the url to that (either directly in your address bar or by clicking an appropriate link)?

Comment: @NicholasTower exactly... when the user enters `http://localhost:3000/players` it will show the data, but if the data is changed the component do not updates

Comment: Hi! Just do clarify. Do you mean that when you first load the page data is loaded but when data is changed on the server/database the the data stays the same?

Comment: hi @Willman.Codes. I mean when the data is received by the react, the table continues empty because the component do not re-render.

Comment: Can you show the code for `Players` or if Players is an external api/library please link?

Comment: Semi related to your question and would eventually be a problem: you need to pass React-Router's props via the callback function `render={(props) => <Players {...props} rows={this.state.players} />`

Comment: [SOLVED] I wasn't using a stateless component. I was so imerse in the problem that  I forgot the basics. I changed for a stateless component and it started working

Answer (score 0):

You can call the route after setting state using `history.push('/players')`.